# "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" headers not being sent on *.s3.amazonaws.com subdomains

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

The below headers are not being sent on *.s3.amazonaws.com subdomain
But, surprisingly they are being sent on not on *.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: HEAD, GET, PUT, POST, DELETE
```

This is for the exact same bucket. Any reason this could be happening? And, how woudld you go about fixing this? I tired disabling & clearing the cache on my browser etc. But the problem persists. I face the exact same problem with the Curl commands as well!

Comment: I think you have misdiagnosed the problem.  CORS is not implemented entirely correctly on S3, because the `Vary: Origin` header is not returned on non-CORS requests, so browsers don't cache things correctly.  This means the headers you get depend on whether your first request for an object is cross-origin or not.  Add an `-h 'Origin: https://example.com'` argument to Curl to confirm.

Comment: I did add Origin headers to the CURL commands. So, currently, the exact same commands are returning the access-control headers after a day. I'm suspecting this could be DNS issues? Now, I could mark these as resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Note: I did add Origin headers to the CURL commands previously when troubleshooting. Currently, the exact same commands are returning the access-control headers after a day. I'm suspecting this could be a DNS issue? Marking as resolved.

Solution: Wait for a day!